# How to get input from an USb xbox 360 controller?

Tags: gamepad

I'm trying to use my wired xbox 360 controller with my Raspberry Pi 3, however xboxdrv seems to not recognize it. I read it could be a power issue because the USB ports on the Raspberry could not deliver enough power. However the 4 LED on the controller blink so it could be another problem.

Comment: Stupid question/sanity check asked only to rule out the simplest possible explanation: Does your controller have a cable permanently attached with plastic strain relief like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Xbox-360-Wired-Controller.jpg) that cannot be removed, or are you using a cable like [this one](http://img.diytrade.com/cdimg/922801/9338136/0/1244688035/Charge_cable_for_Xbox360_controller.jpg)?

Comment: permanently attached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, even though xboxdrv doesn't recognize my controller, I managed to write some code that in fact gets the input. In particular, I've used [this class](https://github.com/FRC4564/Xbox). It says to install xboxdrv, and at this point I don't even know if it uses this driver or the default one, but I'm leaving it as it is.
Also the driver is not perfect: some axis are wrong and the left trigger isn't fully detected, but it's OK.